# Building an interactive website and database that sends emails

Tags: mysql, email, web, joomla, sms

I am tasked with building a website and database with the following requirements:

1. Website must have a place for users to register and be verified.
2. Users must be able to submit forums and get feedback in the form of email or SMS.
3. Users should receive daily updates at a set time.

This is a class project that I am working on with a client outside of the university. I am really hoping to continue it after the semester and develop it into a mobile app. However, I am stuck on where to start here.

I have used Joomla to create websites in the past and I am pretty comfortable with it. I don't know how to get the website forum to update the database. I am also lost on how to get the database to send emails/SMS to the users.

I don't need a step by step guide here, but there are so many options I am not sure where to start.

I need to decide

1. Is Joomla the best system for this kind of website? If not what is?
2. What is the best infrastructure for the database? There is a preference to MySQL as it is open source, but whats the best way to get a database up and running that meets these requirements.

A few closing notes that may be helpful without disclosing too much info about the client, 
- This is going to be a website for weight loss management, and the messages will be encouraging users to make smart choices and congratulating them on completing workouts.
- Estimated number of end users is probably around 5,000

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this easily in Joomla, but you really need to spend some time studying the APIs. If you have used joomla already you know it has an api for sending email to users, but most likely you would be better off using an extension that is designed for this kind of mailing. Personally, because of the legal issues and dangers of sending mass email (getting marked as a spammer etc) I would in general use an extension that supports an external mail service such as Mail Chimp.  I would look in the [extensions directory](http://extensions.joomla.org) and find an option that works for you.